# Azure Logic Apps and VMs

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-virtual-machine, azure-logic-apps

I'm searching for some ideas, how to create an logic app which can turn on/off a VM.

Microsoft Azure team answered on a similar question a couple of months ago, but no any results till today. Does anybody have an idea, is there a way to implement it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way - create a webhook that will call an Azure Function that will shutdown a VM.

Comment: I'm not experienced in creating it, do you have some example?

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the Azure Automation service/connector from logic apps to run a PowerShell script to shut down a VM. Azure Automation has some samples in their gallery that do this.